# Forcing WCF to use HTTPS

Tags: wcf, https

How do I ensure my WCF service is over HTTPS and all communication is over HTTPS?

Theres nothing in my web.config file of the service that says http://... or https://....

HTTPS is set up in IIS and I can access the web service via http and https.

Or is this not required if it's encrypted anyway with message level security?

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS is HTTP over Transport-Layer Security (TLS). To enable it, you need to configure your binding to use transport security in addition to the existing message-level security:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks, do I have to change `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />` to `<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />` as per @Vano Maisuradze's answer too? That seemed to work.

Comment: This only changes your service itself (the web-service bit), not the metadata exchange or the ability for users to browse to the service discovery page (when you go http://domain/myservice.svc in a browser). If these have to work via HTTPS, you need to go further, as Vano has described.

Answer (score 2):

here is config for https:

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfTransport.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyHttpsBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurityBinding" contract="WcfTransport.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors >
    <behavior name="MyHttpsBehaviour" >
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurityBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

note that `httpsGetEnabled` is set to true and `httpGetEnabled` is set to false. You can also remove mex endpoint if you don't need metadata exchange.

p.s. Message security is for message encryption, but of course, you can use message security with https.

Comment: So just doing `<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />` makes it go over HTTPS? It seemed to work but I'm unsure now based on @Programming Hero's answer

Comment: Yes. It accepts only https requests. Also you can remove http binding in IIS and add only https binding.